Product of closed sets is closed in product topology
I have this formula:
Let $X,Y$ two sets and condsider $C,E\subseteq X, \hspace{3pt} D,F\subseteq Y$.
It's true that $(C\times D)\setminus (E\times F)=\left((C\setminus E)\times D\right)\cup \left((C\cap E)\times (D\setminus F)\right)$.
Now, my teacher want to show that if $X,Y$ are two topological spaces, $F$ is a closed set in $X$ and $G$ is a closed set in $Y$, then $F\times G$ is a closed set in $X\times Y$ with respect to the product topology.
So, he did this:
$$(X\times Y)\setminus (F\times G)=\left((X\setminus F)\times Y\right)\cup \left(X\times (Y\setminus G)\right)$$ and concluded saying that it's a closed set because it's the complement of an open sets.
It's seems correct but it is contradictory with the formula provided above.
It should be like this:
$$(X\times Y)\setminus (F\times G)=\left((X\setminus F)\times Y\right)\cup \left(F\times (Y\setminus G)\right)$$
but then how can I say that $F\times G$ is a closed set?

You're right that your version would be what results from the top formula, but your professor's version is also a valid formula, even if it doesn't result from the top one (and is the one we want to apply to get your main result).
Perhaps there was a different general formula that was also presented, and he derived his version from that?
Try drawing what happens when $X$ and $Y$ are both $\mathbb R$ and $F$ and $G$ are both intervals to see what happens.

Yes, you have convinced me!

I reread the question, and I could see your point better. I updated the answer to reflect that.

I think that my teacher used that one he used to say that the union is an open set,  but it didn't motivate the set-theoretic step too much and that's why it didn't work for me, I only knew the first formula I wrote.

Yeah, there's just some overlap in your professor's version.
